# Which SQL statement is faster

Tags: optimization, performance, sql, sql-server

My co-worker claims that using a parameterized Like statement is equivalent to dynamic sql and won't have its execution plan cached for reuse. He says that using `sp_executesql` will allow the execution plan to be cached, increasing the performance of identical searches. However, in the context of this query, the argument doesn't seem to make sense.

Any way to prove one way or the other?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_Person]
        @SearchText varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Declare @SQLString nvarchar(500)
        Declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@SearchText varchar(50)';

        SET @SQLString = N'Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%''';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                              @SearchText = @SearchText;
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        --OR

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like '%' + @SearchText + '%'
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server, right?  Which version?

Comment: @CheranS - Sql Server 2005

Comment: Hopefully you will get a good answer, but what stops you from A/B testing it? Properly measuring performance  is a very good skill to have. For instance http://stuq.nl/weblog/2009-01-28/why-many-java-performance-tests-are-wrong

Comment: @Leonid - I took your advice and conducted an experiment. Please see my results below. Any additional comments you may have concerning my conclusions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming the `EXECUTE...` one isn't vulnerable to SQL Injection, what about your ad-hoc query?  (Sorry, I'm not up on how SQL Server handles that type of stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx):

> SQL Server can avoid compilations of previously executed queries by using four mechanisms to make plan caching accessible in a wide set of situations.
>
> - **Adhoc query caching**
> - Autoparameterization
> - Prepared queries, using either **sp_executesql** or the prepare and execute method invoked through your API
> - **Stored procedures** or other compiled objects (triggers, TVFs, etc.)

In other words, both of your examples should fit SQL Server's criteria for query caching, since one is an ad-hoc query that will be textually the same each time it is run, and the other is a prepared query using `sp_executesql`.

In addition, it appears that either one would appear in a stored procedure, which itself should have a query execution plan cached. The `sp_executesql` approach may be slightly slower because it's doing more work to set up the query, but it's possible that SQL Server actually precompiles the call into something that resembles the second query.

*As in all cases of optimization, the only way to be sure is to test both approaches against your expected data set.*

The second (ad-hoc) query is much more readable, in my opinion. All else being equal, I'd go with that.

Comment: In case you're interested, I conducted an experiment based off the information you provided. I have posted it as a follow up answer to my own question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Armed with the [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx) and information provided by [@StriplingWarrior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2844/striplingwarrior), I conducted an experiment and am posting it as an answer to my own question. Please feel free to comment if I have erred in my conclusions.

## Assumptions

SQL Server can avoid compilations of previously executed queries by using four mechanisms to make plan caching accessible in a wide set of situations.

- **Adhoc** query caching
- Autoparameterization
- Prepared queries, using
  either **sp_executesql** or the prepare and execute method invoked
  through your API
- **Stored procedures** or other compiled objects
  (triggers, TVFs, etc.)

SQL Server stores it’s caching plans in a metadata table called sys.dm_exec_cached_plans

## Examining the cache

**LEGEND:**

- **Proc** (Stored procedure) – “By default, the cached plan will be reused for all successive executions…. unlike the plans cached and reused with sp_executesql, you have an option with stored procedures and user-defined scalar functions to force recompilation when the object is executed.”
- **Prepared** (Prepared statement) – ”The stored procedure sp_executesql is halfway between adhoc caching and stored procedures. Using sp_executesql requires that you identify the parameters and their datatypes, but doesn’t require all the persistent object management needed for stored procedures and other programmed objects.”
- **Adhoc** (Adhoc query) – “…even when SQL Server caches your adhoc queries, you might not be able to depend on their reuse. When SQL Server caches the plan from an adhoc query, the cached plan will be used only if a subsequent batch matches exactly.”

**DATA:**

1. Determine what caching mechanisms are used outside the context of a stored procedure

   Running the attached query **NoStoredProcs.sql** (see Resources section) yields the following results:

   [image: Query Results 1]

   You can see that the Query executed with sp_executesql has its query plan cached as a  Prepared type while the inline statements were cached as Adhoc types.
2. Determine what caching mechanisms are used within the context of a stored procedure

   Running the attached query **WithStoredProcs.sql** (see Resources section) yields the following results:

   [image: Query Results 2]

   SP_Get_Person1 – Proc & Prepared

   SP_Get_Person2 – Proc

   SP_Get_Person3 – Proc & Adhoc

**CONCLUSION:**

It would seem that since there was no additional Adhoc cache plan created for **SP_Get_Person2** that its structure can stand on its own (within a Stored Procedure), in terms of database caching. This can be confirmed by the fact that an Adhoc cache plan was created for this query outside the context of the stored procedure, but not when placed inside the stored procedure.

## Performance

**LEGEND:**

- **Client processing time** - The cumulative amount of time that the client spent executing code while the query was executed.
- **Total execution time** - The cumulative amount of time (in milliseconds) that the client spent processing while the query was executed, including the time that the client spent waiting for replies from the server as well as the time spent executing code.
- **Wait time on server replies** - The cumulative amount of time (in milliseconds) that the client spent while it waited for the server to reply.

**DATA:**

**SP_Get_Person1**
[image: Query Results 3]

**SP_Get_Person2**
[image: Query Results 4]

**SP_Get_Person3**
[image: Query Results 5]

**CONCLUSION:**

From the results above, I can only conclude that any performance gains or losses between **SP_Get_Person1** and **SP_Get_Person2** are inconclusive/negligible since the average total execution time consistently differs in terms of microseconds. However, it is interesting to note that the average time for **SP_Get_Person3** is significantly lower. I would strongly caution that this is not necessarily evidence of a reliable performance gain since every search would result in a new Adhoc query (SQL server did not autoparamatarize this query during my tests). Therefore it is inconclusive what the effect of a growing set of Adhoc queries would have on the database. Furthermore, we lose the safety of typed parameters when using this method.

## Resources

**NoStoredProcs.sql**

```
use DemoDatabase

dbcc freeproccache;
GO
DECLARE @SearchText varchar(50)
SET @SearchText = 'Abatemarco'
Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like '%' + @SearchText + '%'    

GO
DECLARE @SearchText varchar(50)
SET @SearchText = 'Abatemarco'
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%''', N'@SearchText varchar(50)',
                      @SearchText = @SearchText;

GO
DECLARE @SearchText varchar(50)
SET @SearchText = 'Abatemarco'
EXECUTE ( 'Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like ''%' + @SearchText + '%''')

GO
SELECT usecounts, cacheobjtype, objtype, [text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans P
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (plan_handle)
WHERE cacheobjtype = 'Compiled Plan'
    AND [text] NOT LIKE '%dm_exec_cached_plans%';
```

**WithStoredProcs.sql**

```
use DemoDatabase

dbcc freeproccache;
--DROP PROCEDURE [SP_Get_Person1]
--DROP PROCEDURE [SP_Get_Person2]
--DROP PROCEDURE [SP_Get_Person3]
GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_Person1]
            @SearchText varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            EXECUTE sp_executesql N'Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%''', N'@SearchText varchar(50)',
                                  @SearchText = @SearchText;
    END

GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_Person2]
            @SearchText varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like '%' + @SearchText + '%'
    END
GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_Person3]
            @SearchText varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            EXECUTE ( 'Select * FROM PERSON Where LASTNAME Like ''%' + @SearchText + '%''')
    END
GO

    --SET STATISTICS IO ON
    --SET STATISTICS TIME ON 
GO

    Execute [SP_Get_Person1] @SearchText = 'Abatemarco'

GO

    Execute [SP_Get_Person2] @SearchText = 'Abatemarco'

GO

    Execute [SP_Get_Person3] @SearchText = 'Abatemarco'

GO

    --SET STATISTICS IO OFF
    --SET STATISTICS TIME OFF 
GO
    SELECT usecounts, cacheobjtype, objtype, [text]
    FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans P
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (plan_handle)
    WHERE cacheobjtype = 'Compiled Plan'
        AND [text] NOT LIKE '%dm_exec_cached_plans%';
```

## Tools

Statistics were gathered using the **Include Client Statistics** button in SQL Server Management Studio. Only the last 10 query results are stored and averaged. The results can be cleared from the menu: **Query** -> **Reset Client Statistics**.

[image: Client Statistics Button]

[image: Client Statistics Tab]

Comment: Nicely done. What I find particularly interesting is that `SP_Get_Person3` appeared to do better on *every* trial run. If its performance gain was due to caching the entire query, I would have expected it to take as long as the others on at least the first trial run. Did you clear the query cache before starting the test? I'd also be curious to see how the performance would compare if you used a different search string for each test.

Comment: Very cool indeed. I do not have anything to add at this point other than a question - which tools did you use to get that cool summary and how?

Comment: Thanks @Leonid - See my edit above. I added a section for the tools.